# Balance not going up in deepbit after mining

Tags: cgminer, gpu-mining, pool-payout-methods, miner-configuration

I've been mining with a deepbit account and noticed the balance hasn't been increasing. I use the following bat file to run cgminer version 3.5.0

`cgminer.exe -o http://pit.deepbit.net:8332 -u emailme@gmail.com_one -p 123abc -I 10 -g 1 --auto-fan --queue 1 --temp-target 70 --gpu-engine 945 --gpu-memclock 275 --temp-overheat 80 --gpu-fan 75-85  -k diablo -v 2 -w 256`

After upgrading to 3.5 when I press `q` to quit Windows gives me the error "Display driver stopped responding and has recovered".

Here's a screen shot of it working
[image: running cgminner]

What should I do to find out why it's not working?

Comment: I'm not sure how long you have waited but if you plug your hashing rate into a mining calculator and see that after 24 hours at 63/MHS you should earn .00005 BTC roughly 4 cents in USD then subtract your cost of electricity which I would guess is a couple hundred watts at an average of $.15/kwh you can figure out how much it costs you to earn that much BTC you will see your earnings are in the negative.  Plus you may or may not have a driver issue based upon your other comment, I would visit the manufacturers website and see if there is an updated driver.

Comment: also it may or may not help but the most current revision of cgminer that supports GPU mining is 3.7.2 might be worth the upgrade.

Comment: I don't pay for electricity. Could you provide a link to the most current cgminner? I have the latest video card driver.

Comment: http://ck.kolivas.org/apps/cgminer/ don't get the newest cgminer as 3.8 drops support for GPU and scrypt mining.  3.7.2 is what you want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you mining with proportional rewards or PPS?

If proportional then you get paid when a block is found. That can take several days at the size Deepbit is now. So things are most likely working, it just takes time.

Comment: It was just slow, took a few days